# Parenting Objects to armature changes position

Tags: armature, parent

I made this Palkia model which is made of several objects (for example the wings arms) that I parented to the main body. Now I started rigging it for animation, but I only want the main body rigged and the other objects to follow it when posing in pose mode. Just like when you move it in object mode.

In order to achieve this I parented the objects to the armature, but somehow this changes their position or rotation. I've included pics to make it easier to understand (to show I did it with the shoulder piece). Does someone know what I did wrong.

Before Parenting
[image: before parenting]
After Parenting
[image: after parenting]

Comment: Hey, have you set keyframes to the object before clearing parent?

Comment: no i didnt. I also didnt clear the parent because it automatically cleared it after parenting to the bone. But imma go try this out. Thanks

Comment: i could also take a closer look on your file, if you could share a link via wetransfer - if you like...

Comment: https://we.tl/t-dazOcVal8a here u go. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

i took a closer look on the rig and this is what i found:

[image]

1. All objects of the character were parented to the body and had no vertex groups, only body was parented to armature and had vertex groups. They were parented to the body-object, but the armature had no influence on them still.

[image]
2. There are too many separate objects. It makes the character incredibly difficult to weightpaint. Keep the model as simple as possible - or - as complicated as really necessary.

[image]
3. There were different transformations on the model and the armature.
Im not 100% sure, but this may have caused the shoulder bug. I assume the shoulders had a transformation related to the world origin - and the armature had a transformation related to the world origin too.

When you parent the object to the armature with weights, the transformations get mixed up + there is additional influence from the rig.

Anyone please correct me, if I'm wrong.

But to avoid such errors, make sure the armature ist centered and the model as well. Also make sure you apply all transformations before parenting.

[image]
4. Loops of armor is not matching to body at some parts. That makes trouble in weightpainting. Extrude armor from body, if you can.

[image]
5. trouble with automatic weightpainting
-->arms too close to head -> arm bones deform head
--> model character in t or a pose to avoid that

6. You would have to parent "Ellenbogen" bones to root bone, not arms. Otherwise you get depedency cycle between those bones and that makes arm unusable.

Here is your file back: https://we.tl/t-IP1Wo7iwz9
I hope my answer was helpful and let me know if it helped.

Comment: ok holy shit. Didn't expect such an extensive answer but its very much appreciated. Im gonna try to work through all of this tomorrow. By the way, sorry if you had trouble understanding things since everything is in german. I probably should have renamed the objects before.

Comment: hey, no worries, i played with the rig, so i understood the function of every bone. And elbow and ellenbogen sound very familiar ^^